# make a for loop pause and update html page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<script>
var sequence=['trafficred.jpg','trafficamber.jpg','trafficgreen.jpg'];
document.getElementById("sequenceholder").innerHTML = sequence.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colour;

for (i = 0; i < 3;) { 
var colour=sequence[i]
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colour;
i++;
}
</script>
```

I want it to cycle the colours and print each one to the webpage, but it just jumps straight to the end of the list, i'm assuming it needs to wait and let the page update but I don't know how to do that, I tried setTimeout but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly did you try with `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Try to launch your script in the `onLoad` event or add it at the very end of your HTML so it is only executed when everything is ready

Comment: Why is the `i++`inside the loop's body and not as the last clause of the `for` loop?

Comment: @litelite the only explanation is that I am a javascript noob, I will change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setInterval

```js
var i = 0;
var intervalHandler;
var sequence=['trafficred.jpg','trafficamber.jpg','trafficgreen.jpg'];
document.getElementById("sequenceholder").innerHTML = sequence.toString();

intervalHandler = setInterval(function(){
var colour=sequence[i]
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colour;
i++;
if(i>=3) {
 clearInterval(intervalHandler);
}
},1000)
```

```html
<div id="sequenceholder">

</div>
<div id="demo">

</div>
```